# Where is the write protect screw on chromebook C330

Tags: chromebook

I’m trying to remove the write-protect screw or switch on my Chromebook C330. Where is it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this Chromebook by removing the write-protection? Have you checked the system documentation yet? Do you own this Chromebook?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Lenovo forums](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Chromebooks/Lenovo-300e-chromebook-write-protect-screw-location/m-p/4267529), the C330 does not contain a write protect screw like some other Chromebooks.

> In order to go to developer option, you need to boot to the recovery mode then press control + D or enter to delete local data and reset the machine.

Answer (score 0):

According to a [more-than-year-old Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/chromeos/comments/cmmc6h/installing_another_distro_on_the_lenovo_c330/), that particular model doesn't have a write protect screw. The OP in the thread wanted to install a Linux distro and was told that doing so is particularly challenging, due to the ARM architecture.

If your objective is to reset the machine, Karu's answer is more appropriate, I suspect. If not, the reddit post answer links may generate an alternative.